# onClick appears to work on all but my iphone

Tags: iphone, sencha-touch-2

For some reason the following html doesnt work inside safari on iphone 4.

`<a href="#" onClick="function(){alert("here");preventDefault();}" ><div class="sell-light marketBttn">Test Link</div></a>`

it works on safari inside a regular browser. I am using senchatouch2 framework.
Thanks

Comment: OT: <div> in <a> is now allowed, use <span> instead.

Comment: However the span suffers in the same way a link that is wrapped seems to not work in the iphone. I will for the moment have to have the link inside.<a href="#" onClick="alert(\'works\')"><span>I work</span></a>

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can add events to dom elements in Sencha touch 2.0 that I know of, is to use their element events api. this is an example of it. Alot of events are available like tap, double tap and so on.

```
var el = Ext.get("test");
    el.addListener( 'tap', function(e){
    alert('it works!');
});
```

This goes after the panel is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I propose that you do not use such inline event handlers.
Not only is it better to separate markup and behavior, but you should let sencha touch handle the messy business of unifying events across browsers.
At the very least give your tag an id and do `Ext.get('id').on('tap', function(){...})`
But still better look into MVC features to avoid such low-level code altogether.

Comment: I know this good information it is an edge case forcing me down this direction.